# MAUI Blazor: Implementation of AAD or Auth0 not possible?

Tags: authentication, maui, maui-blazor

If I understand it correctly, a full implementation of authentication via Azure AD is currently not possible in MAUI (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/azure-mobile-apps/quickstarts/maui/authentication?pivots=vs2022-windows => "This tutorial currently supports a limited set of platforms. Specifically, the iOS platform is not covered at the moment.")

If you look at it on the other side with Auth0, there is a problem with Windows (see https://auth0.com/blog/add-authentication-to-dotnet-maui-apps-with-auth0/ => "For example, at present, integration in Windows is not yet possible (check this issue and the related work in progress), ...")

What seems to be left is to create a login yourself. But it would be really great if the user could avoid registering with their own email and instead use a Google, Microsoft or iOS account.

I've been looking for possible solution for a long time, but it looks like there is nothing suitable at the moment.

Or has anyone figured out how to log in to a MAUI Blazor app using a Google, microsoft or iOS account?

Thanks

Comment: Can this case about [MAUI AAD Authentication ClaimsPrincipal with IsAuthenticated always false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74233407/maui-aad-authentication-claimsprincipal-with-isauthenticated-always-false) help you?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that's not really what I need.